# Dynamic links in menu (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, symfony, hyperlink, menu, twig

I'm working with Symfony and I want to add menu bar to my site. I have a simple menu bar with 3 links that are static and always be the same like "Home" but I need to add new links that should be dynamic. I have my admin panel where I can add new pages (info about them is stored in database - title, content etc.) and what I want to achieve is that after adding a new page, a link to this page should appear in this menu. I have this menu in my header.html.twig file which I include to every page same as footer.

Best of what I was able to achieve at that moment:

DefaultController.php

```
public function headerAction ()
{
    $news =  $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('AppBundle:News', 'n')
        ->select('n')
        ->where('n.type = :news')
        ->setParameter('news', 'other')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    $parsedown = new Parsedown();
    foreach($news as $key => $new){
        $news[$key]->setContent($parsedown->text($new->getContent()));
    }

    return $this->render('default/other_menu.html.twig', array(
        'news' => $news
    ));
}
```

header-menu.html.twig

```
{# some bootstrap #}
{# simple static links #}

{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:header')) }}

{# simple static links #}
{# some bootstrap #}
```

other_menu.html.twig

```
{% for new in news %}
<a href="{{ path('show_other', {id: new.id}) }}">{{ new.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But this solution works only when I have one page in database. With more of them - one long link is created (page1page2page3)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try to do a `dump($news);` what do you have ?

Comment: Two element array. First element:
0 => News {#1166 ▼
    -id: 2
    -title: "About us"
    -content: "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>"
    -createDate: DateTime {#1179 ▶}
    -type: "other"

Comment: ok, so it s an array, and what is your Parsedown() ?

Comment: It's just for Markdown.

Comment: and when you dump news in the twig template ? you have an array or a string like page1page2page3 ?

Comment: In other_menu.html.twig I have the same array i wrote before.

Comment: and you don't have all the different link displayed when you loop on the array ?

Comment: Ok, it's two separate links wihout space between. I didn't notice it, sorry. But maybe you will know how to adjust this:
    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:header')) }}
to this something like this (my static links):
    <a class="mdl-navigation__link {{active == 0 ? 'is-active' : ''}}" href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Homepage</a>

Comment: When I add something like to my loop in other_menu.html.twig I have error like this: Variable "active" does not exist.

Comment: and it's right ! ...

Comment: Why dont you use KnpMenuBundle

Comment: Because I can't. I must write it on my own.